# generating xls documents representing model objects keep being read as corrupt in excel 2010

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, export-to-excel, xls

I'm generating an xls document for each item of my model WeeklyReport. I have the basic structure of the document working, but I'm finding small changes keep making the file be read as corrupt and unopenable by Excel 2010, and I don't really understand why. I've been using the railscast here:http://railscasts.com/episodes/362-exporting-csv-and-excel to figure out how to do this.

In my model controller, I have the following:

```
def show
    @report=WeeklyReport.find(params[:id])
    @engagements=@report.engagements
end

def index
    @reports=WeeklyReport.all
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.xls
    end
end
```

And in the show.xls file, I have the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
  xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
  xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
  xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
  xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
  <DocumentProperties xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
    <Author>OurAppName</Author>
    <Created><%= @report.created_at%> </Created>
  </DocumentProperties>
  <Worksheet ss:Name="Engagements">  
    <Table>
      <Row>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">First Name</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Email</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Date</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Version</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Rating</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Comment</Data></Cell>
      </Row>
      <% @engagements.each do |e| %>
      <Row>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String"> <%= e.user.first_name%></Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String"> <%= mail_to("#{e.user.email}")%></Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String"> <%= e.created_at.strftime("%B %d, %y")%></Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String"> <%= e.version_made %></Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String"> <%= e.rating %></Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String"> <%= e.comment %></Data></Cell>
      </Row>
      <% end %>
    </Table>
  </Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

I'm trying to understand what makes the files be read as corrupt. I adjusted the document in excel to look like how I want it to, and then am trying to reverse engineer it. When I just copy and pasted the xls code into the app (figuring I would go back and change it to iterating over the data after I got it working), it said the file was corrupt. When I make small changes of all sorts, it says the file is corrupt.
Here are some of the things that have made the file be corrupt:

- Changing the rating data cell type to Number
- Copying over the style information from the xml document I saved the excel file as
- Adding column width information
  Basically, I don't understand why it is making the files corrupt and what is causing them to be corrupt, it seems like it just happens half the time for no reason (obviously not the case)

I want our admins to be able to download the files with confidence. I also get a warning when opening the files that "The file you are trying to open is in a different format than specified by the file extension. Verify that the file is not corrupted and is from a trusted source before opening the file. Do you want to open the file now?"

Most of the answers I'm seeing about dealing with corrupted files that aren't really corrupted in Excel involves changing the protection settings for trusted documents. I don't think it is an appropriate solution to this problem, as it will reduce the security of our admins computers.

How can I create secure (as in, reads as trustworthy and not-scary for our less technical admins), non-corrupt xls files? What I've been doing clearly isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out, for the most part, why this is happening. In the case where I set the type to number, it is corrupt because `<%= e.rating %>` is a string. Even though the rating is an Integer, the embedded ruby returns a string. I think most of the rest of the time, I'm not quite closing the tags right. The numbers thing was the most confusing problem.